# Compare list of Vector with Desired String Matches - If Not a Match Delete DF Row R

Tags: r, data-cleaning, stringr

I'm interested in creating a vector containing keywords that are the correct titles for what is contained in the category column of a separate data frame.  I'd like to be able to create a function to compare down the category column for matches against the keyword vector, and if they're not there, deleting the incorrect row from the data frame.

Here is an example of desired keywords:

"Current SharePrice","Current NAV", "Current Premium/Discount", "52WkAvg SharePrice", "52WkAvg NAV", "52WkHigh Premium/Discount" etc etc.

I'm trying to remove a few edge cases from a large table where the cleaning produced results such as:

"52WkLow NAV 52wLow"

This occurs due to missing data.  Additionally, as a redundancy check, printing or storing which full rows were removed in the cleaning would be hugely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
filter(df, category %in% keywords)
```

(and the lines removed:)

```
filter(df, !(category %in% keywords))
```

Base:

```
df[df$category %in% keywords,]
```

removed lines:

```
df[!(df$category %in% keywords),]
```

Comment: And "keywords" in either case can be referencing a character vector with multiple elements? Thank you.

Comment: yeah, plug in the name of your vector instead of the word "keywords", your category for "category" and your dataframe for "df".

Comment: Thank you, I will!

Comment: Strangely when I then spread what should be the cleaned table the incorrect values are still in there.  Here are my steps: the original three column df is called data2 columns "Ticker, Category, Value."        
test_clean_removed <- filter(data2, !(Category %in% keywords))
test_clean <- filter(data2, Category %in% keywords)

test_tab <- test_clean %>% spread(Category,Value)

Comment: Are you sure dplyr is loaded? Try dplyr::filter to make sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186891/discussion-between-js80-and-iod).